# How to store select2 array of values in database as text using Laravel POST request

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, laravel, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 plugin in Laravel form:

```
<select id="productTags" class="form-control mt-2 select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" multiple="multiple" name="productTags" data-select2-id="productTags">
<option value="adidas">adidas</option>
<option value="asics-tiger" data-select2-id="7">asics-tiger</option>
<option value="autumn" data-select2-id="8">autumn</option>
<option value="backpack">backpack</option>
<option value="cap">cap</option>
<option value="converse">converse</option>
<option value="drmartens">drmartens</option>
</select>

<select id="productVendors" class="form-control mt-2 select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" multiple="multiple" name="productVendors" data-select2-id="productVendors">
<option value="ADIDAS">ADIDAS</option>
<option value="ASICS TIGER">ASICS TIGER</option>
<option value="CONVERSE">CONVERSE</option>
<option value="DR MARTENS" data-select2-id="12">DR MARTENS</option>
</select>
```

To submit the form I'm using simple inline form:

```
<form method="POST" action="store_catalog" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Whats submitted in the database is just the first result like "ADIDAS" but what I need to be submitted in the database is multiple values from the select2 field so in the database I need to store array like:

```
"['adidas', 'asics-tiger']"
```

SO how I can store array with values intead just first value from select2 ?

I know I can use jquery to format data but can I store a simple array as a text in the database without jquery?

Comment: Send the value as array by changing the name attribute value; `name="productTags[]"` should do it. Have you tried that?

Comment: I got error: ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Array to string conversion

Comment: Your php is not okay, the form is now posting an array. You could check that with `dd(request()->input('productTags'))`

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/LjHlxEUx - yes PHP send the array to backend

Comment: If you want the array to be stored as a value in your database, you should change your model. Check this; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting